# Getting Textboxes to Clear after use

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an access form where I input data into them to be inserted into a table for storage, the code I use is

```
Private Sub cmd_go_Click()
Dim insertstring As String

insertstring = "INSERT INTO KWTable (KW, Source, Code) VALUES('" & text_key.Value & "','" &         combo_source.Value & "','" & txt_code.Value & "');"

DoCmd.RunSQL insertstring

End Sub
```

And I was wondering if there was a code I could add to this so that once the data has been inserted the text box and the combo box would automatically clear?

Answer (score 1):

Use the properties of the controls. Specifically, try setting the `.Text` or `.Value` properties to `""`:

```
txtTextBox.Text = ""
```

Or:

```
txtTextBox.Value = ""
```

Comment: @user2119980 anywhere *after* you use the values of the controls

Comment: Going to be a bit pedantic and say best practice is to use `vbNullString` instead of `""`. Saves a few bytes!